# Find all possible values of $(-i)^{i}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all possible values of $(-i)^{i}$.

Here is my attempt:

$(-i)^{i}=\mathit{e}^{ilog(-i)}=\mathit{e}^{i(log|-i|+iarg(-i))}=\mathit{e}^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}=\mathit{e}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$, where $n$ is an integer.

However, the answer is $\mathit{e}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-2\pi n}$. Why is $2\pi n$ being subtracted?

Comment: If $n$ goes over all the integers, what difference does it make?

Comment: Note that $\ker(\exp))=2\pi i \Bbb Z$.

Comment: $2\pi n$ should be multiplied by $i^2$, not just $i$

Comment: $-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$, so $(-i)^i=e^{\pi/2}$. However, since $e^{i2\pi}=1$ we could multiply by $e^{i2n\pi}$ (for any positive or negative integer $n$) before taking to the power of $i$, thus getting $\left(e^{-i(\pi/2+2n\pi)}\right)^i=e^{(2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the solutions

$$e^{\frac\pi2 - 2\pi n}\>\>\>\>\> \text{and} \>\>\>\>\>e^{\frac\pi2 + 2\pi n}$$

are equivalent for $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 1):

Since $i^2 = -1$, we will need to multiply our result by $-1$...to wit:

$$e^{i (\ln |-i| + i \arg (-i))}$$
$$e^{i (\ln 1 + \frac {3 \pi i}{2} \pm 2\pi i k)}$$
$$e^{i (0 + \frac {3 \pi i}{2} \pm 2\pi i k))}$$ 
$$e^{i (\frac {3 \pi i}{2} \pm 2\pi i k)}$$
$$e^{(-\frac {3 \pi}{2} \pm 2\pi k)}$$

The last answer is fine on its own, but using Quanto's answer above, each of the coterminal angles can be taken either clockwise or counterclockwise.  Some books imply the exponential is positive, so in this case, we can use the coterminal angle to express this (i.e. $-\frac {3 \pi}{2} = \frac {\pi}{2})$; thus $$e^{(-\frac {3 \pi}{2} \pm 2\pi k)}\equiv e^{(\frac {\pi}{2} \pm 2\pi k)} $$

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I'm having trouble with Math.Jax but -i is exp(((4n+3)(pi)/2)i) so the answer is exp((-(4n+3)(pi)/2), where n is any integer.